# Anaconda Installation Issues

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I'm having a ton of issues getting Anaconda to work on my machine (Windows). Up until yesterday I've been able to run without any issues (for the past several years), but out of the blue it stopped working.

After attempting a full re-install, I'm getting the following error message when I attempt to run anything in the Conda prompt:

*'"[0x7FFF636A7E30]"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

*Could Not find C:\Users\rileyn\[0x7FFF636A7E30]*

Not sure why that text is being appended to the user directory. I'd bet that's the issue, but I have not clue how to fix. It's persisted through several attempts at uninstall/reinstalls.

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
I'm also getting a *ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used* message anytime I run a conda command, and that same 0x7FFF... key is attached to the message as well.

Comment: your username is "username"? does the message literally say "Could Not find C:\Users\username[0x7FFF636A7E30]"?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for responding. No, just using that as a placeholder. The error shows my actual username.

Comment: then put your actual error. Does your username have any special character? if you put an error, put the actual error. Your placeholder might be hiding the actual error. Then the next question is. Did you change your username recently?

Comment: Done. No special characters. No recent username changes.

Comment: Ok, see? you posted `username[0x7FFF636A7E30]`  and in reality is `rileyn\[0x7FFF636A7E30]` which means that the [0x7FFF636A7E30] is not part of the username but a subfolder (since there's a "\" separating both). Now how are you installing Anaconda? Did you download the Installer file from the official website? By default anaconda should install to `C:\Users\rileyn\anaconda3`. Can you check if such folder exist in your system?

Comment: Sure thing. The stackoverflow text logic removed the backslash so I had to double it. Thanks for catching that. I did perform the default installation, and yes there is a folder at C:\Users\rileyn\Anaconda3.